# Chrome USB API interruptTransfer failed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, usb, google-chrome-app

I'm having issues to establish communication with a usb device using [chrome.usb APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb)
I've been trying the all day but I always get the same error.

> usb.interruptTransfer: Transfer failed

Code:

```
var PRODUCT_INFO = {
"vendorId": idhere,
"productId": idhere
}

function allInOne() {
// find and open USB device
chrome.usb.findDevices(PRODUCT_INFO, function (arrayConnection) {
    if (arrayConnection && arrayConnection.length > 0) {
        console.log("Device opened");
        var connectionHandle = arrayConnection[0];
        console.log(connectionHandle);
        // list all interfaces
        chrome.usb.listInterfaces(connectionHandle, function (interfaces) {
            console.log(interfaces);
            //choose the first
            var interface = interfaces[0];
            //claim the interface
            chrome.usb.claimInterface(connectionHandle, interface.interfaceNumber, function () {
                //transfer
                chrome.usb.interruptTransfer(connectionHandle, {
                    "direction": interface.endpoints[0].direction,
                    "endpoint": interface.endpoints[0].address,
                    "length": interface.endpoints[0].maximumPacketSize
                }, function (event) {
                    //log data
                    console.log(event);
                });
            });
        });

    } else {
        console.log("device not found");

    }
});
```

}

Interface:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your device posting data for you to read on the interrupt pipe? It could be failing because nothing is available. I recommend a USB protocol analyzer that can be attached between your host and your device so that you can look at the USB data on the line - it will be especially helpful in cases like this where you are abstracted from the USB APIs that provide more detailed error codes.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar issue today where my USB device just didn't want to work and I had the same "Transfer failed" error. Pretty old question by now but I'm posting this for anyone that might find this in the future.

My solution was two-fold:

1. Specify the interfaceId in all the INFOs as well (along with vendor and product ids) e.g. `{ "vendorId": 1118, "productId": 672, "interfaceId": 0 }`
2. VendorId and ProductId should **always** be decimal numbers and not hex (even though Google examples show otherwise). The docs for this API are all slightly out of sync with the current reality it seems.
3. Ensure that I called `chrome.usb.claimInterface` before attempting to call `chrome.usb.interruptTransfer` and `chrome.usb.releaseInterface` after I was done.
4. Surround everything with a try-catch inside the callback in `chrome.usb.interruptTransfer`

Below is a link to a working example code I know works, perhaps it can help you identify what might be going wrong in yours: 
https://github.com/sverrirs/XboxBigButton/blob/master/Examples/ChromeApp/xboxusb.js

Comment: The base you use to write the vendor ID and product ID should be irrelevant; decimal and hex are just two ways of writing the same number in Javascript.

Comment: Agreed, but in practice it does seem to matter. The google docs indicate that the manifest.json must have decimal values but I've found that this holds for the rest of the code as well. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#manifest